# Defining a line of two equations in three varibles for subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$U=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3:x−y+2z=0\}$ is a vector space.

Define the line 
$V=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3:−x=y=z\}$.
The set $V$ is seen to be a line as the points in $V$ satisfy two linear equations in three variables, giving one degree of freedom. Then $V$ is a subspace of $U$.

Same if we define 
$T=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3:x=2−y=1−z\}$
and $W=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3:−x=2y=z\}$ but here neither $T$ nor $W$ are subspaces of $U$.

My issues here is.. how those three line definitions are formed from $x−y+2z=0,$ $
−x=y=z ,\; 
x=2−y=1−z,$ and $
−x=2y=z$

Answer (score 0):

Let's describe the spaces in terms of linearly independent vectors (a basis for each space). For the plane, take $y=1, z=0$, then substituting into the equation of the plane we have $x=1$...so the vector $(1,1,0)$ is in the plane. Now take $y=0, z=1$, then (substituting again into the equation of the plane) we have $x=-2$, so that $(-2,0,1)$ is in the plane. Now $(1,1,0)$ is not a multiple of $(-2,0,1)$, so that they are linearly independent and therefore a basis for the plane.

Now consider the first line: if we have $y=z=1$, then we must have $x=-1$, so that $(-1,1,1)$ is a vector on the line, and since the line is only dimension 1, this vector is then a basis for $V$. Now it is easy to see that $(-1,1,1)=(1,1,0)+(-2,0,1)$, so that this basis vector is in the span of the basis vectors of the plane, and therefore the line is a subspace of the plane.

Now $T$ is a problem, since it is not even a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (any subspace must contain the zero vector $(0,0,0)$). But we can still check whether $T$ is a line in the plane $U$: the easiest way to do this is to substitute the line equation into the plane directly as given. So from the line equation you have $-y=2-x$ and $z=1-x$, substitute into the equation for the plane: $x+(x-2)+2(1-x)=2x-2+2-2x=0$ for all $x$. So it is clear that this line is indeed actually in the plane, but since it does not contain the zero vector it cannot be a subspace.

Lastly, $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, so let's just get a basis for it: Take $y=1$, then we have $x=-2, z=2$, so $(-2,1,2)$ will do. Now to check whether the basis of $U$ together with this vector is linearly dependent you can construct a matrix with columns (or rows) the basis of $U$ and this vector, so for example: \begin{equation} \begin{bmatrix} 1&1&0\\-2&0&1\\-2&1&2 \end{bmatrix}, \end{equation} and then just check the rank is less than 3, or calculate the determinant. You will then see that this matrix is full rank so that the three vectors are linearly independent and the line is not in the plane, and hence not a subspace. Another, perhaps simpler way, is to use the same method as above and just substitute directly into the equation of the plane and see if it satisfies the plane equation...

I'm not sure if this answered your question, but just to add this, to "get" a line that is in the plane you simply have to take any linear combination of the basis vectors, and then multiply by one of the parameters $x,y$ or $z$ to get a parametric definition for the line. For example, we know $(1,1,0)$ is in the plane...multiply by $x$: then you have $(x,x,0)$...so that a subspace of $U$ will be the line $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x=y,z=0\}$.